# Menu completely disappears when re-sized

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, navigation

I am using this simple plugin to convert exist menu into responsive menu, its working smoothly here (http://bit.ly/1xdGxh9) but some problem is there.

On a desktop/laptop, when the browser is re-sized appropriately (to a mobile device size), the menu action works as it was designed. However, when viewing on a mobile device, i.e. an Android phone, the menu doesn't work.
 When viewing in landscape, the menu completely disappears. I even tried view the "demo" on this site and received the same results. here is the plugin link http://bit.ly/1edvEFN

Comment: Could you please give us the relevant code that might give us an idea as to what is going on? (HTML, CSS, JavaScript...)

Comment: thanks for reply here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/wkwz1pv0/